# highlight different regexp groups with different colors

Tags: regular-expressions, search, highlighting

Is there a way, that each group in regexp can be highlighted with a different color.

For example, if I am searching for

```
\(text_part_1\)\|\(text_part_2\)
```

Can the `text_part_1` be highlighted in one color and `text_part_2` in another color?

Comment: Are you stuck on using Helm, here? If you are open to other possibilities, [Icicles search](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Search_Commands%2c_Overview#SearchHighlightingContextLevels) does exactly what you are asking.

Comment: Yes, I am open to other possibilities. The documentation screenshot shows exactly what I want. I will try it and close this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No need to close the question. You will no doubt get good answers, including about using Helm for this. I will add an answer that mentions Icicles support for it. And I imagine there are other approaches, with or without Helm.

Comment: I edited my answer to mention that you can get the same kind of highlighting with [Isearch+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IsearchPlus).

Answer (score 2):

If you use [Isearch+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IsearchPlus), or if you use [Icicles](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles), then you can get [this kind of regexp-group highlighting](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Search_Commands%2c_Overview) when you use Isearch or [Icicles search](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Search_Commands%2c_Overview), respectively.

For example, this screenshot shows highlighting for this input regexp:

`(\([-a-z*]+\) *\((\(([-a-z]+ *\([^)]*\))\))\).*`.  It shows 4 levels of subgroup highlighting plus highlighting (level 0) of the full regexp match.  (Up to 8 highlighting levels are possible.)

[image]

Whether to highlight regexp subgroups is controlled by option **`isearchp-highlight-regexp-group-levels-flag`** in Isearch and by option **`icicle-search-highlight-context-levels-flag`** in Icicles search.

In Isearch you can toggle regexp-group highlighting anytime while searching by hitting **`M-s h R`**.  (In Isearch+ while searching, prefix key `M-s h` controls various kinds of highlighting.)  Only the current search hit shows regexp-group highlighting, but the other search hits have their odd and even regexp groups highlighted differently, to easily distinguish them.

---

> **`isearchp-highlight-regexp-group-levels-flag`** is a variable defined in `isearch+.el`.
>
> Its value is `t`
>
> Documentation:
>
> Non-`nil` means highlight 1-8 regexp group levels, within search hit.
>
> You can toggle this value using **`M-s h R`** during Isearch.
>
> You can customize this variable.

---

> **`icicle-search-highlight-context-levels-flag`** is a variable defined in [`icicles-opt.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/icicles-opt.el).
>
> Its value is `t`
>
> Documentation:
>
> Non-`nil` means highlight up to 8 context levels, within the search context.
>
> Level highlighting is done only when this is non-`nil` and a subgroup is
>   not used as the search context, that is, the context corresponds to
>   the entire search regexp.
>
> Remember that you can use multi-command `icicle-toggle-option' anytime
>   (**`M-i M-i'** during completion) to toggle an option value.
>
> You can customize this variable.

The **faces** used for regexp-group highlighting in Icicles search are `icicle-search-context-level-1` through `icicle-search-context-level-8`.  In Isearch they are faces `isearchp-regexp-level-1` through `isearchp-regexp-level-8`.